# A circuit for polynomial multiplication

Tags: shift-register

I first want to say that I have absolutely no knowledge in circuit theory or any sort of electrical engineering stuff. I am a math major studying coding theory, and I am currently reading Error Correction Coding by Todd K. Moon.

Section 4.9 'Some Hardware Background' of this book gives a really short introduction to circuit; it explains about one-bit memory storage, adders and multiplications. Soon after this introductory part is over, the book explains about polynomial multiplication, that is the hardware implementation to calculate \$b(x)=a(x)h(x)\$ where
$$a(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_kx^k$$
$$h(x)=h_0+h_1x+h_2x^2+\cdots+h_rx^r$$
so that the product is $$b(x)=a_0h_0+(a_0h_1+a_1h_0)x+\cdots + (a_kh_{r-1}+a_{k-1}h_r)x^{r+k-1}+a_kh_rx^{r+k}$$
The book gives two circuits that solve the problem.
[image]
[image]
I have managed to understand Figure 4.1, but I still don't get Figure 4.2. If \$a_k\$ is given as the input, then \$a_kh_r\$ should be the output, but I don't understand why that should be the case, since all of \$a_kh_0+a_kh_1+\cdots+a_kh_r\$ should be present in my opinion. Could anyone explain this clearly please? Also, the book also mentions that the second circuit has the advantage for hardware implementation, and is suitable for higher-speed operation. Why is that so? Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first circuit is conceptually easier to understand. a<sub>x</sub> gets delayed along the input shift register, so that when all the a are multiplied by the h, the terms line up, producing a single value of b.

However, the problem is in that very wide adder that produces b. It's a purely combinatorial circuit with deep delay paths. If you were laying out an FPGA or ASIC to implement this, the large fan-in is going to cause a lot of routing inefficiency. It doesn't scale well, a few extra stages may result in a lot more routing area. You could pipeline it for speed, but that's going to consume a lot of extra area, registers, and routing.

The second circuit needs to tilt your head to one side to understand. Now instead of a being delayed on the way in, b is delayed on the way out, so there are many partial b sums working their way along the output path. If you 'play computer' with a pencil and paper, and track the indexes through the calculation, you'll find that they produce the same answers. Both styles even need the same number of clocks to shift through their pipelines when starting from cold before they start producing the correct answers.

The great advantage of this is that each adder simply adds two terms, before being captured in a register. The delay path is as short as it can be for an adder, allowing higher speed than the first configuration.

The second configuration is so important that most FPGA manufacturers produce an optimised hard-routed MAC cell, a Multiply ACcumulate cell, that puts the multiplier, adder and register stages into a single unit, and usually includes dedicated high speed local routing to the next MAC in the same column, which does not consume any of the programmable general purpose routing. This optimises speed, power, and routing resource.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and thank you for your elaborated explanation. There are still some parts that I don't fully get(for example, the second paragraph and the last is a little bit hard for me to digest). However I have understood the second figure at last, and that would be fine for me. Again, thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo You probably won't get the second and last paragraphs until you come to lay out an FPGA, and find your timing and space constraints hammered by the first configuration. An example from my employment - I created a filter-based design for FPGA. The original proof-of-principle design in MATLAB and then C used the first configuration, it was easier to see what we were doing and be convinced that we'd got it right. We used these to generate some test vectors, before we implemented the second configuration in VHDL, and made sure it produced the same as the test data.